# pdoPage не выводит результаты

Tags: php, ajax, modx

Мне нужно отфильтровать результаты и я отправляю ajax запрос и там уже вызываю сниппет.

```
$page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : '1';

$results = $modx->runSnippet('pdoPage', array(
  'parents' => $category[0],
  'resources' => $resources,
  'element' => 'msProducts',
  'totalVar' => 'products.total',
  //'ajaxMode' => 'button',
  'ajaxTplMore' => 'more-button',
  'tpl' => 'good-row',
  'depth' => '1',
  'limit' => 0,
  'showHidden' => '0',
  'includeThumbs' => '320x415',
  'sortby' => 'createdon',
  'sortdir' => 'DESC',
  'includeTVs' => 'filter-age, filter-sex',
  'page' => $page
));
```

Проблема в том, что если стоит параметр 'ajaxMode' => 'button', то ничего не выводится. Без него все отлично работает.

Может еще какие-то параметры передать надо, или после ajax что-то вызвать?

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать хотя бы?

Answer (score 1):

[https://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/snippets/pdopage#Загрузка-кнопкой](https://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/snippets/pdopage#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9) - если почитать инструкцию, то там написано что `При нажатии на кнопку загружаются &limit элементов и добавляются в конец блока результатов` - а у тебя &limit=0. С большой вероятностью ошибка именно в этом.